# Using pandas explode where data not actually a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I'm importing from a text file. The file is organized where certain columns include multiple pieces of data separated by comma. In effect, for certain indices in the df the column value is a list. However pandas isn't reading the data as such, rather as a string that happens to include commas. (Example in the MRE below)

What I ultimately want to do is use `df.explode` to expand these columns into separate rows but first I need to get pandas to recognize the data as a list. Obviously I could loop through the whole df but there's got to be a vectorized solution here.

Sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_data = {'Day': ['Mon', 'Tues', 'Weds', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
        'Visit':['MK', ['E', 'DAK'], 'MK', 
                ['DHS', 'E'], 'E', ['DAK', 'DHS', 'E'], 'MK'],
        'Visit2':['MK', 'E, DAK', 'MK', 
                'DHS, E', 'E', 'DAK, DHS, E', 'MK']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data = df_data)

print(df.explode('Visit'))
print(df.explode('Visit2'))
```

The data I'm dealing with looks like column `Visit2` but what I want is something like `Visit`. **OR** some other data transformation that ends up with the desired result:

```
     Day Visit
0    Mon    MK
1   Tues     E
1   Tues   DAK
2   Weds    MK
3  Thurs   DHS
3  Thurs     E
4    Fri     E
5    Sat   DAK
5    Sat   DHS
5    Sat     E
6    Sun    MK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can convert your Visit2 to Visit with `str.split()`:

```
df['Visit2']= df['Visit2'].str.split(',')
```

And then when you do:

```
>>> print(df.explode('Visit2'))

     Day          Visit Visit2
0    Mon             MK     MK
1   Tues       [E, DAK]      E
1   Tues       [E, DAK]    DAK
2   Weds             MK     MK
3  Thurs       [DHS, E]    DHS
3  Thurs       [DHS, E]      E
4    Fri              E      E
5    Sat  [DAK, DHS, E]    DAK
5    Sat  [DAK, DHS, E]    DHS
5    Sat  [DAK, DHS, E]      E
6    Sun             MK     MK

# Or drop the column first

>>> print(df.drop('Visit',axis=1).explode('Visit2'))

     Day Visit2
0    Mon     MK
1   Tues      E
1   Tues    DAK
2   Weds     MK
3  Thurs    DHS
3  Thurs      E
4    Fri      E
5    Sat    DAK
5    Sat    DHS
5    Sat      E
6    Sun     MK
```